# Trying to add toolbars in Windows Explorer: they are greyed out

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, toolbar

I am trying to add toolbars in Windows Explorer. However, they are greyed out:

[image]

Unchecking `Lock the toolbars` doesn't help:

[image]

How can I make then selectable again?

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

---

I run `gpedit.msc` the run window:

[image]

and went to `User Configuration->Administrative Template->Start Menu and Taskbar`. According to it, users are not prevented from adding toolbars:

[image]

Explicitly disabling `Prevent users from acting on removing toolbars` and rebooting the computer didn't help.

Maybe there is some registry keys that turn on/off the capacity of adding toolbars?

Comment: Have you tried implicitly enabling it?

Comment: There's this 3rd option: Lock the toolbars. Have you tried unlocking it, then trying to enable one? ;)

Comment: @LPChip good point, I have just tried though and it didn't help.

Comment: @Ramhound Sounds good, I'll try next time I reboot the computer.

Comment: Force a group policy update through the command

Comment: @Ramhound Explicitly disabling `Prevent users from acting on removing toolbars` and rebooting the computer didn't help.